# How do I expose state properties from my add on component to the developer?

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently experimenting with creating add-ons in Ember 3.8 and I'm a bit stuck on how to expose state properties to the developer. I have a simple button in my addon:

```
//ui-button/component.js

import Component from '@ember/component';
import layout from './template';
import { oneWay } from '@ember/object/computed'

export default Component.extend({
  layout,
  tagName: '',

  type: 'button',
  task: null,

  isRunning: oneWay('task.isRunning'),

  disabled: oneWay('task.isRunning'),

  onClick(){},

  actions: {

    click(){
      event if 'type' = submit)
      event.preventDefault();

      let task = this.task;

      let onClick = this.onClick;

      task ? task.perform() : onClick();
    }
  }

});

//ui-button/template.hbs

<button onclick={{action "click"}} disabled={{disabled}} type={{type}}> 
  {{yield}} {{if disabled "..."}}
</button>
```

The tasks and actions simply live on `application controller`:

```
buttonTask: task(function*() {
    yield timeout(2000)
    yield alert("Clicked after 2 seconds")
}),

actions: {
    clicker() {
        alert('clicked')
    }
}
```

I can call it from an ember project like this:

```
<UiButton @onClick={{action "clicker"}}>
  Angle Bracket
</UiButton>

<UiButton @task={{task buttonTask}}>
  Angle Bracket with task
</UiButton>
```

and it works fine, but I'd like to be able to give the developer access to `disabled` or `isRunning` so that they can add their own behaviour.

I tried to create an intermediate component that yielded out the properties:

```
//ui-button-yield/template.hbs
{{yield (hash
    button=(component "ui-button"
        task=@task)
    isRunning=task.isRunning
    disabled=task.disabled
 )
}}
```

and call it like this:

```
{{#ui-button-yield as |button|}}
  {{#button.button task=buttonTask}}
    Handlebars Yield {{if button.isRunning "!!!"}}
  {{/button.button}}
{{/ui-button-yield}}
```

But although the button works I can't access either of the `disabled` or `isRunning`properties from the codeblock. Furthermore, according to Ember Inspector these properties aren't available on the `ui-button-yield` component, only the `ui-button`.

Comment: why do you even want this? Why not just access `isRunning` on the `buttonTask` directly.

Comment: That is a super relevant question and occured to me a little bit later - I used a bad example with `isRunning` as the `disabled` would have been more appropriate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you `yield` from `ui-button-yield` but you've defined `isRunning` and `disabled` in `ui-button`.

If you really want to use this wrapping contextual compoent then you need to move your logic to it.

Comment: This was obviously correct. I ended up restructuring the entire component to remove the `ui-button-yield` wrapper. The wrapper itself was only there because of a misunderstanding about contextual components!

Answer (score -1):

You got very close but your consuming template needs to be setup a little differently

```
{{#ui-button-yield as |button isRunning disabled|}}
  {{#button.button task=buttonTask}}
    Handlebars Yield {{if isRunning "!!!"}}
  {{/button.button}}
{{/ui-button-yield}}
```

You may also want to consider:

```
{{#ui-button-yield task=buttonTask as |button isRunning disabled|}}
  {{#button.button}}
    Handlebars Yield {{if isRunning "!!!"}}
  {{/button.button}}
{{/ui-button-yield}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've not seen multiple "arguments" after `as` before, are these needed even if you expose the properties in the `{{yield`}} hash of the consuming template?

Comment: Yes, they are. `yield` **allows** the consuming template to use values but they aren’t pulled into the consuming template unless you specifically opt-in as a consumer. That protects consumers from having their own variables stomped on by addons

Comment: No they are not. If you use `hash` you create a wrapper object.

Comment: Ah, @Lux is right, I missed the use of the hash helper. It comes of answering questions too early in the morning ...  Sorvah if you stop using the hash helper you can use the api I described. Otherwise your usage is accurate